# How can I get shell-command-on-region bound to M-| (when it's not)

Tags: key-bindings

So from what I've read on other posts, the emacs command `shell-command-on-region` should be bound to the key `M-|`.

This works on one system but not on another system so I'm trying to define the key binding.
So far I don't have the right syntax.
I have tried each of the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-|") 'shell-command-on-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "M|") 'shell-command-on-region)
(define-key global-map "\M-|" 'shell-command-on-region)
```

But none work.  I either get a syntax error in the escape sequence or no error but the key binding doesn't work as expected.

NOTE: I'm pressing `Alt+Shift+\` keys.
NOTE: the `Shift+\` key is the `|` key on my keyboard (if that matters).  This key combination works on one system but not on another.

On both systems when I type on the keyboard the `\` key and the `Shift+\` key produce the desired keys which are `\` and `|`.

And on both systems, when I run Also `describe-key` for the key `\` and `Shift+\` produce the same info:

> \ runs the command self-insert-command (found in global-map), which is an interactive built-in
> function in ‘C source code’.
>
> It is bound to many ordinary text characters.
>
> (self-insert-command N &optional C)
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 22.1.
>
> **Insert the character you type.**

**System that works**
Emacs version: GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-koji-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30, cairo version 1.15.12) of 2023-04-03

Also `describe-key` says:

> M-| runs the command shell-command-on-region (found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.
>
> It is bound to M-|,    .

**System that doesn't work**
Emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2020-04-03 on x86-01.bsys.centos.org

And `describe-key` for `Alt+Shift+\` says:

> | is undefined

Comment: What do you get from `Ctrl+h` `k` ``Alt+Shift+\`` (i.e. `describe-key`)?

Comment: If it works on one system but not another then **specify those systems in your question**.

Comment: ... and also clarify if `Shift+\\` produces '|' on both systems or not. If not, what does it produce?

Comment: Updated the question to include the answers to the above questions.

Comment: So if you type `\ ` or `Shift+\ ` in a terminal (outside of Emacs) on the second system, what does that give you? IOW, is Emacs relevant at all or are there deeper problems?

Comment: `| is undefined` shows that the key sequence which was sent to Emacs did not include a Meta modifier (or at minimum that it did not know how to interpret it as such; but I'd be surprised if Emacs was *discarding* any of the input events, so I expect your problem is independent of Emacs).  I suggest running `xev -event keyboard` from a shell, and finding out what's actually going on when you press the `Alt` key (and you might compare and contrast with your other system).

Comment: Good point! I had forgotten that in some cases Linux, or even a hypervisor had **snatched** some keystrokes without sending the keys to the app.   I won't be able to test this out for a few days but I'll look into your reasoning.